# how to set absolute positions of axis in core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm working with core plot on iPhone now, and I'm trying to set up the ScatterPlot graph in such a way that [0,0] coordinates are always at the same place (that is 40 pixels from the left and 40 pixels from the bottom)

I just wasted 4 hours trying to get this to work, and still have no idea, help!

Bonus question - how to set up axises to make only the >0 parts visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 40.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 40.0;
```

Bonus:
Setting the padding will move the axes and plot area so your origin is offset from the left and bottom by 40px.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple :)